# Finding first row in dataframe that matches condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. My first dataframe has two columns, which I would like to use to create a condition and return a value from the second dataframe.

```
df1 = (['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], [0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.6])

df2 = (['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], [0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.1, 0.4], 
              [500, 200, 900, 400, 250, 800])
```

For each row in df1, I would like to look up df2 by the two columns of data. The first condition is to match the letter in df1 with df2. The second condition is to lookup the first number row in df2 where the number is greater than df1. If no number is greater, take the first row in df2 that matches the letter.

My target output is:

- df1 row[0] = 500 # 'a' matches 'a' & 0.4 is greater than 0.2
- df1 row[1] = 200 # 'a' matches 'a' & 0.9 is greater than 0.6
- df1 row[2] = 900 # 'b' matches 'b' & no row is greater than 0.1 so return first 'b' row
- df1 row[3] = 800 # 'c' matches 'c' & 0.6 is greater than 0.4

Apologies for any poor formatting with my question, please provide any advice regarding posting (its my first one).

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

I think better is avoid iteration.
I merged data from `df1` and `df2` together by column `a`. Output has twice more rows as original `df1`. Then condition is applied by np.where and output is cast to integer. Series `s` contained output, each odd value. (because merging with one rows from `df1` with two rows from `df2`)

```
#   a    b
#0  a  0.4
#1  a  0.9
#2  b  0.1
#3  c  0.6

#   a    c    d
#0  a  0.2  500
#1  a  0.6  200
#2  b  0.3  900
#3  b  0.8  400
#4  c  0.1  250
#5  c  0.4  800  

#merged data - intersection df1 and df2 by column a
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a'], how='inner')
#apply condition
s = np.where(df['c']< df['b'], df['d'], df['d'].shift(1)).astype('int')
#odd values
s = s[1::2]
#[500 200 900 800]

#if need add data do df1 as column e
#df1['e'] = pd.Series(s, index=df1.index)
```

iteration solution (Delforge):

```
100 loops, best of 3: 4.67 ms per loop
```

merged solution (me):

```
100 loops, best of 3: 1.93 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, I've been playing around with your solution, and it looks very good. Regarding your last line of code, you look up odd values to add the data back to the original dataframe. The actual data I'm working with has varying lengths per element (as I could have three values in column c for one element in column a, and five values for another in column a). What is a good way to look up the results you store in s and add them back to df1? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate df1 and make a selection base on column 0 letter and greater than comparison between the two columns 1. Assuming that your column 1 values are ascending, if the selected dataframe is not empty store the last value of the column 2. If empty get the first value of df2 col 2 that match column 0 selection.

Here is an example, I store the results in a dictionnary.

Example:

Your data

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], [0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.6]]).transpose()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], [0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.1, 0.4], [500, 200, 900, 400, 250, 800]]).transpose()
```

The iteration:

```
results = {} # dictionnary to store results

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    select = df2[(df2[0] == row[0]) & (df2[1] < row[1])] # selection

    if not select.empty:
        results[i] = select[2].iloc[-1] # storing last value of column 2
    else:
        results[i] = df2[df2[0] == row[0]][2].iloc[0] # storing first value if no greater than match

print results # {0: 500, 1: 200, 2: 900, 3: 800}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, this solves my problem very nicely.